# Laravel оптимизация изображений, плагин Intervention images

Tags: laravel, изображения, оптимизация

У меня следующая ситуация, использую laravel 10 и установил Intervention images для оптимизации изображений. Все изображения которые оптимизрую приходят с "мой склад" и при попытке оптимизации нескольких изображений появляется предупреждение:

libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB

и за этого данные изображения не сохраняются.

Вот метод который отвечает за сохранение

```
private function importImageToProduct($product, $downloadUrl, $filePath, $roles): void
{
    $filePath = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $filePath));

    $http = Http::withHeaders(['Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip'])->withBasicAuth($this->login, $this->password);
    $response = $http->retry(5, 120000)->get($downloadUrl);

    Storage::disk('public')->put('images/products/'.$filePath, $response->getBody());

    // здесь начинается оптимизация
    $img = Image::make(Storage::disk('public')->path('images/products/'.$filePath))->resize(
        1000,
        null,
        function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        }
    );
    $img->save(Storage::disk('public')->path('images/products/'.$filePath), 80);
}
```

как можно это исправить?